# Python - function changing input list, although I made a copy

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am writing a small python script that prints out a list of lines where the lines themselves are a list of string. This is what the function does. It is supposed to take the list as input and print out the nice version, without actually changing the list. I can get it to print out the right output. But upon closer inspections it also changes the original list although the first thing I do in the function is to make a copy of the original list using this `grid_copy = grid[:]`

**Problem**: The script turns any `''` into `' '` although I do not modify the list

`[['X', 'X', ''], ['', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', '']]`

into:

```
[X] [X] [ ]

[ ] [O] [O]

[O] [X] [ ]
```

I do not know what is causing the list to be changed, no where am I referencing the original list except when I make the copy in the beginning.

My code includes several useful comments that I added to make it easier to understand what I did. If you run the code there is also a test case I provided.

```
def show_grid(grid):
    """
    grid: list. A list of lines, where the lines are a list of strings
    return: None
        Prints the grid out in the classic 3x3
    """
    grid_copy = grid[:]  # make a copy so we do not want to actually change grid
    len_grid = len(grid_copy)  # I use this so much, might as well store it

    # add whitespaces to make each single spot the same width
    len_digits = len(str((len(grid_copy)**2)))  # the number of chars wide the highest number is
    # modification happens somewhere vvv
    for line in range(len_grid):
        for char in range(len_grid):
            grid_copy[line][char] = str(grid_copy[line][char]).rjust(len_digits)  # proper white spaces

    # modification happens somewhere ^^^

    # add brackets, THIS IS NOT WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
    for line in grid_copy:
        print('[' + '] ['.join(line)+']\n')  # print each symbol in a box


# TESTING TESTING
test_grid = [['X', 'X', ''], ['', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', '']]
print('test_grid before: {}'.format(test_grid))
show_grid(test_grid)  # this should not modify test_grid, but it does
print('test_grid after: {}'.format(test_grid))
```

OUTPUT:

```
test_grid before: [['X', 'X', ''], ['', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', '']]
[X] [X] [ ]

[ ] [O] [O]

[O] [X] [ ]

test_grid after: [['X', 'X', ' '], [' ', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', ' ']]
```

Comment: Btw, the [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)'s still useful, and it should always be your first visit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `grid_copy = grid[:]` on a list of list, you are only copy the topmost list but not the element of the list itself. This is called a **shallow copy** opposed to a **deep copy**. You should write

```
grid_copy = [x[:] for x in grid]
```

or

```
grid_copy = copy.deepcopy(grid)
```

Comment: so I my list was just a list of string rather than a list of list my method would work?

Comment: A list of string should do what you intended, because str's are immutable.

Comment: @Vader: coping a list of string with l[:] is ok because strings are immutable (meaning that you cannot modify a string in Python). So it doesn't make any use to copy a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use the source, Luke! (Sorry, I had to)

This is the difference between shallow copy and deep copy. This is explained in details in the documentation of the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html). Shallow copy only takes care of the first level container, populating the copy with references to the contained objects. Whereas deep copy also copies contained objects.